# Remove SVN content from old Java files

Tags: java, svn, rename

I have to make changes in an old project we did years ago and our company used SVN in that time (now we have GIT). I tried to run that project in Eclipse, but I discovered that all files have extensions *.java,v (that was easy to fix), but also all files include content like this

```
head    1.2;
access;
symbols
   HR_struts:1.2.0.2
Root_HR_struts_start:1.2
Konec_hybridu_060602:1.2;
locks; strict;
comment @# @;


1.2
date    2006.05.05.05.48.50;    author moncka;  state Exp;
branches;
next    1.1;
```

So I suppose that is the relic of our SVN usage. And my question is how to delete this content by using any tool (project contains thousands of files).
Thanks a lot for help.

P.S. Project also includes files like .jsp, .xml and so on which are spoiled too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of files with names ending `,v` it sounds like it was [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) rather than Subversion that was being used and that what you have is a copy of the repository rather than just a working copy of the project.

You don't want to just strip this content from the files because that will not leave you with an intact copy of the most recent version of each file.

You could try setting up a CVS server for the repository and doing a checkout to get a clean copy of the latest version of the source files. Alternatively, now that you're using Git it might be worth investigating `git-cvsimport`. Converting a repository with that is fairly straightforward.

Comment: You could also try using RCS directly, since that was used by CVS. I'm not sure if CVS stored additional metadata somewhere. If you have RCS installed, try `co foo.java` if you have a file `foo.java,v`. If you want to edit the file, use `co -l foo.java` - that will lock the revision. See `man rcsintro` for more info.

Comment: Yeah, thats possible, we also used CVS according to my colleagues. Well, I would like to avoid setting up a CVS server, because we dont have one anymore and it sounds to me like a overkill. I will try importing it from GIT, that could work. And dont worry about having a most recent version, it was just old files sitting on the hard drive, nobody didnt make any changes to them for ages. Thanks for advice

Comment: Thinking about it, going down the `git-cvsimport` route is possibly a better idea as that will also preserve the history of all the files too. As a quick way to check you have a complete copy of the repository, do you have files with names like `modules`, `cvsrc`, `config` etc at the top level?

Comment: No, I dont see nothing like that in the project folder. Well I will go with git-cvsimport and let you know what happened:-)

Comment: If you don't see those files then you might not have the complete repository and might need to do individual files as suggested by @ChristophSeibert

Comment: Ok, so after some investigation I've discovered that we still have a CVS server installed under Linux but it's not running and I can't figure out how to pull that project or where to find it in the system. I tried to look to the CVSROOT directory and it's nothing interesting there. So any help is appreciated, google is really not helping me out...

Comment: If you're OK to email me one of the `,v` files I'll take a look over the weekend and see if I can do anything with it (contact details are in my profile.)